# Signalr Client version 1.5, server version undefined

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have signalR v2 installed and referenced on my page

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

But somewhy I get error message in browser debugger:

Error: You are using a version of the client that isn't compatible with the server. Client version 1.5, server version undefined.

I guess the problem is that client appears to be 1.5 version. There are other packages installed in the project such as Autofac SignalR 2 Integration but I guess they do not influence on client version.

Answer (score 9):

The problem occurred because all the strings in camel case were transferred to snake case by the component of another developer. The version of the signalR was stored in one of the variables with changed case and script didn't manage to find out the version cuz the variable with version was undefined. Hope this'll help someone.

Comment: I am getting this exact error but i am not sure what you're saying i need to look for in my project to see if the same thing has happened here?

Comment: Yes, in my case some other custom code is interfering with standard jquery ajax.